# Auto Scroll TextView in a CustomListView

Tags: android, android-listview, scroll, textview

i am trying to make my textview that is in a customlist view scroll.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/listview_patientname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:hint="Patient Name"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Above is my xml code and i have set my listview to be selected.

The above xml and together with setting a textview that is not in a listview scroll.

Is there a solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use this:

```
    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

     <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

      </RelativeLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

ScrollView can contain only one child. so put another layout in it and then put your views.

Comment: Hi i dont quite understand the answer . I have to put my textview in relativelayout? If there is the case wont i be needing 1 scrollview and layout for every textview in my cutom listview ?

Comment: put all your views in the ScrollView under the RelativeLayout and they all be scroll able.